# Deleting file from shared app group

Tags: swift, ios-app-group

I have a function that successfully moves a file into the shared App group, but my function to delete that file does not seem to be working.  If I print out the fullpath2 variable it appears to be the correct location but the file is not removed and an error is not returned.

Here is my function:

```
func getSharedFilePath(appGroup:String,sharedFilename:String)->URL? {

if let directoryPath = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) {
    return directoryPath.appendingPathComponent(sharedFilename)
} else {
    return nil
}
}


public func deleteFromSharedFile(sharedFilename: String, fileExtension: String)->String {
let sharedFilename = "\(sharedFilename).\(fileExtension)"
guard let url = getSharedFilePath(appGroup:applicationGroup,sharedFilename:sharedFilename) else {
    return("Error getting shared file path")
}

// read file from file system to data variable
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: (url.path))
    return("File Removed")
}
catch let error as NSError {
    return("File Remove Failed - \(error)")
}
}
```

Comment: `url.absoluteString` is wrong. You need to get its path. `try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: url.path)`. BTW absoluteString returns the url scheme also (`file://` in this case) and your are adding it and removing it the next line.

Comment: @LeoDabus Using url.path did not work either

Comment: update your question with your actual code

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry about that - I have updated the question

Comment: You need also post how you are getting the fileURL. What is the error?

Comment: Add print statements to know where your code is actually failing

Comment: @LeoDabus I have added the getSharedFilePath function that is being used to get the shared app group folder.  I do not receive an error message, the code returns "File Removed" but when I look at the app data nothing was actually removed.

Comment: hi can you please give me code for saving the images in share extension and retrieve  in the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code snippet of my emoji app.

It works well.

```
func removeImage(itemName: String, fileExtension: String) {
    let fileName:String = itemName + "." + fileExtension
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    guard let groupURL = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.io.XXXXXX.XXXX") else {
        return
    }
    let storagePathUrl = groupURL.appendingPathComponent("image/" + fileName, isDirectory: false)
    let storagePath = storagePathUrl.path

    do {
       if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: storagePath) {
           try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: storagePath)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

"image" is just the name of sub folder of app group.

If you are saving files directly in the root folder, you can remove it.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`FileManager.default.containerURL(...)` changes each time the app runs.

If you are persisting the location of files to later delete, know that this part of the full file path will be different.